# What a care-taker is taking care of?

Tags: word-choice

I need a good word for the object a care-taker is taking care of. The term will be used in scientific environment, more specifically in IT: we have an application which is "monitoring" other applications's status and in case it senses some "deviation" from normal behaviour it takes specific actions (restart, allocate more resources, etc, not relevant).

But I just don't know how to call these "applications that some other application takes care of" ...

Comment: They are _monitored_? You could also call them _managed_ applications, as opposed to _unmanaged_, but that may cause confusion with _managed_ and _unmanaged_ code in the .NET environment.

Comment: Well, maybe not? That answer is "charge".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably "property" is the best all-around word.

It works perfectly if it is a building-caretaker, and so works nicely for any software modules.